Missing source maps for large first-party JavaScript
PageSpeed Insights is giving me the following warning regarding my first-party javascript file:
Missing source maps for large first-party JavaScript

But that makes no sense to me because the first-party javascript file is not minified. It currently has 13,895 lines.
Is there a way to fix the warning without minifying the first-party javascript file?
I tried putting the reference of the source map of a minified third-party javascript plugin (shown below) at the bottom of the first-party javascript. That fixed the warning, but the console showed a ReferenceError about a variable. Therefore, I have to find an alternative solution.
//# sourceMappingURL=someplugin.min.js.map


What is your ultimate goal here? Just silence all warnings? Or actually improve the page speed?

@Bergi My ultimate goal here is fixing this warning.

But why do you care? Why not just ignore it?

@Bergi It's my client's website, which I was involved in development. His developer is asking me to fix the warning.

You may want to ask them why they care about it then :-) But it seems you already know the proper thing to do: minify the script, so that it both becomes smaller and gets a source map generated for it.
